# Why am I getting incorrect results for these simple operations in Julia?

Tags: floating-point, julia

I've started using the Julia language, but I'm surprised to get seemingly incorrect results with even basic operations:

```
julia> 0.05*0.05
0.0025000000000000005
```

and

```
julia> 1.0-0.85-0.1
0.05000000000000002
```

How can this be? And what can I do to obtain exact results?

Comment: Looks like a rounding error due to approximation.

Comment: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm surprised to get seemingly incorrect results with even basic operations [...] How can this be?

Binary IEEE-754 floating-point numbers ([which Julia uses](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/)) cannot represent numbers such as 0.05, 0.85, and 0.1 exactly.

For instance, when you write `0.05` in Julia, the number that the machine manipulates is a number very close to the actual number 0.05, but not *exactly* 0.05. Therefore, you cannot expect Julia expressions such as `0.05*0.05` to evaluate to exactly 0.0025.

More counterintuitive examples? Try

```
julia> 1-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2
5.551115123125783e-17

julia> 0.6/0.2 == 3
false
```

If you're interested (and even if you're not!), I strongly recommend 
David Goldberg's [*What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic*](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf). You may also be interested in this [related answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116980/why-doesnt-tikzs-foreach-iterate-over-the-last-element-of-the-list/116990#116990) on the TeX sister site.

---

> And what can I do to obtain exact results?

Are you only manipulating rational numbers? If so, know that Julia provides a *rational* types, i.e. types that allow you to represent fractions exactly.

The rational type used by default, `Rational{Int64}`, is capable of representing any rational number whose numerator and denominator fall in the range of 64-bit integers.
You can use this rational type to carry out exact operations (barring integer overflow) on rational numbers:

```
julia> 1//20 * 1//20
1//400

julia> 1 - 17//20 - 1//10
1//20
```

Moreover, if you want [arbitrary-precision](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#arbitrary-precision-arithmetic) rational numbers, you can use the `Rational{BigInt}` type (see [Mr Alpha's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786864/why-am-i-getting-incorrect-results-for-these-simple-operations-in-julia#comment43985726_27786912))

Comment: Julia also has a Rational{BigInt} for when you don't want to deal with overflow.